# Javascript Prototype and inheritance

Tags: javascript, prototype

I come from a conservative OOP language (JAVA) and dont really understand Javascript inheritance. I am also shaky with the whole Prototype concept but I have seen an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29838735/basic-javascript-prototype-and-inheritance-example-for-animals) that answers my need but I dont understand the details and why things are not done differently.

Taking their example, the correct implementation is as follows

```
function Animal(name) {
   this.name = name;
}

// Example method on the Animal object
Animal.prototype.getName = function() {
    return this.name;
}

function Mammal(name, hasHair) {
    // Use the parent constructor and set the correct `this`
    Animal.call(this, name);

    this.hasHair = hasHair;
}

// Inherit the Animal prototype
Mammal.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
// Set the Mammal constructor to 'Mammal'
Mammal.prototype.constructor = Mammal;
```

I do not understand the purpose of the Object.call() function nor do i understand why Object.create() was used and not simply just Animal.prototype. Also why is the constructor being added in the last line? Is it because it is erased in the step before? And what should I do if I wanted to share code in among all Mammal instances?

Thanks in advance

Comment: To answer one of your questions: The methods `call`, `apply` and `bind` of the `Object` prototype are the only way to set `this` directly when invoking a method. Otherwise `this` is determined by the invocation context of the method (the object the method was called on).

Answer (score 0):

If you did not call the `Mammal.prototype.constructor = Mammal;` then the constructor would be Animal() (which is the constructor of Animal.prototype by default)

Using `Object.create()` means Mammal.prototype is not a *reference* to Animal.prototype but instead a new object inheriting that prototype.

And using `Object.call()` ensures the scope is not that of the function calling the method and instead is the scope of the Mammal constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can not extend classes like Java does. You can only simulate something like that.

Animal.call make sure the animal.this does not point to animal but rather point to Mammal. In short the call() function overwrites @this.

object.create simply creates an instance of an empty function with given object as prototype:

```
Object.create = function (o) {
    function F() {};
    F.prototype = o;
    return new F();
}
```

Its only needed when using a child constuctor. If not a simple object will do it as well.

Here is a good advice:
http://javascriptissexy.com/oop-in-javascript-what-you-need-to-know/

Comment: With ES6, it's now possible.