# Simple javascript prototype example

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I am trying to give a simple example of prototype inheritance in javascript but its not running. Kindly help!

**HTML**

```
<script> 
var animal = {eats: 'true'};
animal.prototype.name = "Lion";
console.log(animal);
</script>
```

Comment: Please define "not running".

Comment: Cannot understand what you saying?

Comment: Haha, what you mean when you say "its not running"? It is running, and firing an error, just check the console. `prototype` is a property of functions only ...

Comment: What if I want to add a custom property to an object. Cant I use prototype?

Comment: You could use the prototype of the constructor, but it's useful only when adding methods. Please read [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add properties to a prototype... as long as the prototype actually **exists**. In your case, you have to initialize first the prototype. For example:

```
var animal = {eats: 'true'};
animal.prototype={};
animal.prototype.name = "Lion";
console.log(animal);
```

But a nicer way to define a prototype is:

```
var Animal=function(name){
    this.name=name;
}

// Add new members to the prototype:
Animal.prototype.toString=function()
{
    return "animal "+this.name;
}

// Instance objects:
var a1=new Animal("panther");
console.log(a1.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var Animal = function() {
  this.eats = 'true';
};

Animal.prototype.name = 'Lion';

var a = new Animal;

console.log(a.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Easier way for you. You can use the non constructor way to create objects with existing objects thus using prototypical inheritance in javascript. The other is using functions.

Your animal question has been asked before: [Basic JavaScript Prototype and Inheritance Example for Animals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29838735/basic-javascript-prototype-and-inheritance-example-for-animals) , pls follow other javascript protoytype posts here in stackoverflow as there as numerous and enough time has been spent on them. Utilize and be a pro.

```js
var animal = { name: 'Lion'};
var myanimal = Object.create(animal)
myanimal.eats = "true";
console.log(myanimal.name);
```

Comment: meant to use prototypal inheritance.

Comment: The above example shows how you can prototypically  inherit existing objects without using functions just for a sake of simple example  to understand. Long way to go. you can also use functions and classes in ES6

Comment: @Peterson Added your animal link